# type of return value in itertuples and print column names of itertuples in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
          a         b         c         d
0  0.140603  0.622511  0.936006  0.384274
1  0.246792  0.961605  0.866785  0.544677
2  0.710089  0.057486  0.531215  0.243285
```

I want to iterate the df with itertuples() and print the values and column names of each row. Currently I know the following method:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
for item in df.itertuples():
    print(item)
```

And the output is:

```
Pandas(Index=0, a=0.55464273035498401, b=0.50784779485386233, c=0.55866384351761911, d=0.35969591433338755)
Pandas(Index=1, a=0.60682158587529356, b=0.37571390304543184, 
c=0.13566419305411737, d=0.55807909125502775)
Pandas(Index=2, a=0.73260693374584385, b=0.59246381839030349, c=0.92102184020347211, d=0.029942550647279687)
```

Question:

1) I thought the return data of each iteration is a tuple (as suggested by the function name) when the type(df) returns Pandas()?

2) What is the best way to extract the value of 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' being the column names as I loop through the items of each row?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

To access the values of the named tuple, either by label:

```
for item in df.itertuples():
    print(item.a, item.b)
```

or by position

```
for item in df.itertuples():
    print(item[1], item[2])
```

When DataFrame has more than 254 columns, the return type is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) and the only available access is by position. To be anyway able to access by label, restrict df just to columns you need

```
for item in df.loc[:, [a, b]].itertuples():
    print(item.a, item.b)
```

Comment: my bad. I mean type(item). It returns pandas(Index=0.....etc) as shown from the above output

Comment: you mentioned print item.a, item.b. But this assumed we know the column names in advance already. What we have no idea of what the df and the columns of it are about. Is there a way to loop through / print the columns?

Comment: I agree this slicing will give me the 'values' of the remaining items of the specific row. But what I am looking for are the associated field(columns) of the remaining items of the specific row, i.e. a command that can show 'a','b','c','d'.....depending on the number of items in the row